# Apple, Push notification, Parse, Error: Failed to register

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification, appdelegate

I got an error message of "Failed to register" when I run my app, and I can't see the Installation class in Parse. No idea where I did wrong as I follow the instruction from Parse except the function of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in appDelegate because I have Facebook login. Also, in my app -> target -> general, no error message is shown under the Identity, so I guess my provisioning profile is correct. For the App ID in Apple's member center, I see the distribution of push notification is still Configurable.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    Parse.setApplicationId("......", clientKey: ".........")

    let notificationTypes:UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]

    let notificationSettings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    buildUserInterface()

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I followed these instruction and it worked for me: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/PushTutorial/tree/master/iOS

Also, Parse is shutting down next year, just so you know.